# Insert Data in Server Using JSON

Tags: android, json

I am trying to insert data in server from android application using JSON. But I am getting IP Address Error. Can any one tell me whats wrong in my code? I am uploading my code where the insert action has done. It just gives the Toast - **Invalid IP Address**. But my IP Address is not invalid.

```
public void insert()
{
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",id));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",name));

    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.145/tracker/index.php/json/add_task");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
        Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
    }

    try
    {
        JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
        code=(json_data.getInt("code"));

        if(code==1)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inserted Successfully",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, Try Again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
    }
}
```

Your prompt response is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Invalid IP Address, it is showing because you are giving that text in the Toast, so see what this Log is printing Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());. That is the actual message. And you can use the e.printStackTrace() to see the exact error message.

Comment: @AndroidKiller I know that is because of that Toast. But can you tell me why the IP is not found?

Comment: It may be some other error, you have given the message so you are getting. use e.printStackTrace() function to see the exact error and post it here.

Comment: There might be any other error. But as you are using Exception the parent class of All the classes the catch block will execute for any kind of exception. And as you are passing Invalid ip address string in the Toast String for any kind of exception that Toast will display...By using this toast you cant say yor are getitng Invalid Ip address error..

Comment: Please post your logcat stack trace...

Comment: yes @Raj is right..... you cant say that is a Invalid ip address becuase for any kind of exception that catch block would execute...

Comment: Hello @RajSharma I have solved that IP Address problem :) Please see below I have post my solution there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your responses. I have added the following code under `setContentView(R.layout.activity_insert);` and this solved my IP Address problem.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use this and check whether its working or not

```
public String request(String url, List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs)
{

    try
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        // httpPost.setHeader("encytype", "multipart/form-data");

        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

        UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8);
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try
    {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        reader.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Buffer Error" + "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    return json;
}
```